# Inno Setup Change Caption of an existing radio button on custom options page

Tags: inno-setup

I'm new to Inno Setup. I'm using the Wizard pages to create an installer.
I've created an option page an some input pages.

On these input pages I get some values. Depending on such values I want to change the caption of an radio button already created in the initialize procedure of the wizard.

So, if a user entered `100-701` on an input page, I want to change the radio buttons caption on a later page to something like this:

```
(*) 100-701

( ) Standard
```

Can someone hint me, if there is a way to modify the caption or do i have to create a custom page from scratch?

Thanks,
Klaus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`CreateInputOptionPage` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_createinputoptionpage) returns an instance of [`TInputOptionWizardPage` class](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptclasses&anchor=TInputOptionWizardPage).

The class has `CheckListBox` property of [type `TNewCheckListBox`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptclasses&anchor=TNewCheckListBox), which it turn has `ItemCaption` property.

```pascal
var
  Page: TInputOptionWizardPage;

{ ... }

Page := CreateInputOptionPage(...);
Page.Add('Option 1');
Page.Add('Option 2');

{ ... }

Page.CheckListBox.ItemCaption[0] := 'Alternative caption for Option 1';
Page.CheckListBox.ItemCaption[1] := 'Alternative caption for Option 2';
```